# How do I remove certain vector objects from a list in Clojure?

Tags: list, vector, clojure

I have variable test in Clojure like this:

```
( def test '([:circle {:cx 428, :cy 245, :r 32.2490309931942, :fill red}] [circle] [:line {:x1 461, :y1 222, :x2 365, :y2 163}] [:line {:x1 407, :y1 102, :x2 377, :y2 211}] [line]))
```

I want to remove the [line] and [circle] objects from it and for it to look like this:

```
([:circle {:cx 428, :cy 245, :r 32.2490309931942, :fill red}] [:line {:x1 461, :y1 222, :x2 365, :y2 163}] [:line {:x1 407, :y1 102, :x2 377, :y2 211}] )
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Clojure?

I've looked at this thread [How can I remove an item from a sequence in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939278/how-can-i-remove-an-item-from-a-sequence-in-clojure)

and remove() but I still don't have it. that thread shows:

```
(remove #{:foo} #{:foo :bar})      ; => (:bar)
(remove #{:foo} [:foo :bar])       ; => (:bar)
(remove #{:foo} (list :foo :bar))  ; => (:bar)
```

but for me I have something more like:

```
(remove #????? ([:foo :bar] [foo] [bar]))
```

and I want to end up with ([:foo :bar]) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of `remove`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove):

> `(remove pred)` `(remove pred coll)`
>
> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in `coll` for which `(pred item)` returns `false`.

Thus you need to provide a predicate that does so, for example to remove `[circle]`:

```
#(= '[circle] %)
```

This is a (anonymous) function that test whether it's argument is (value) equal to the vector `[circle]`.

You can, of course, also generalize this to remove all one element vectors:

```
#(and (vector? %) (= 1 (.length %)))
```

Or remove every vector that contains not at least a keyword:

```
#(and (vector? %) (not-any? keyword? %))
```

I hope you get the picture :)

Comment: Thank you! =) I didn't know you could do #(= '[circle] %) as the syntax! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in this exact case you would probably need something like this:

```
(remove (comp symbol? first) test)
```

output:

```
([:circle {:cx 428, :cy 245, :r 32.2490309931942, :fill red}] 
 [:line {:x1 461, :y1 222, :x2 365, :y2 163}] 
 [:line {:x1 407, :y1 102, :x2 377, :y2 211}])
```

as you want to remove all vectors whose first value is `symbol`.

Of course if you want to remove all the vectors with the only value which is a symbol, you should be more specific:

```
(remove #(and (vector? %)
              (== 1 (count %))
              (symbol? (first %)))
        test)
```

You could also invert your logic, not removing unneeded data, but keeping needed one:

```
(filter (comp keyword? first) test)
```

output:

```
([:circle {:cx 428, :cy 245, :r 32.2490309931942, :fill red}] 
 [:line {:x1 461, :y1 222, :x2 365, :y2 163}] 
 [:line {:x1 407, :y1 102, :x2 377, :y2 211}])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your code just like the examples you have provided from the thread using a `set` of elements as the predicate for your `remove` (or some other functions), you only need to put the elements you want to get rid of inside of the `set` (just as you almost have done), but you need to be aware of symbols which need to be quoted.
So the first possible error-cause in your last example is not quoting the list of your vectors:

```
(remove #????? ([:foo :bar] [foo] [bar])) ;; this list can not be evaluated and
;; will cause an error
(remove #????? '([:foo :bar] [foo] [bar])) ;; make it a varied list by quoting it
```

Now you need also to quot the symbols inside of the `#{}` as predicate:

```
(remove #{['foo] ['bar]} '([:foo :bar] [foo] [bar])) ;; => ([:foo :bar])
```

Same rules apply also for your first example:

```
 (remove #{['line] ['circle]} test)
 ;;=> ([:circle {:cx 428, :cy 245, :r 32.2490309931942, :fill red}] 
 ;;    [:line {:x1 461, :y1 222, :x2 365, :y2 163}]
 ;;    [:line {:x1 407, :y1 102, :x2 377, :y2 211}])
```

will clean up your list of vectors.